# Jenkins - Publish Over SSH - EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR - bash: service: command not found

Tags: bash, jenkins, ssh, exec

I have issue with Publish Over SSH plugin and already try so many possible solution, but still doesn't work:

1. using exec in pty
2. using bash --login
3. using shebang (#!/usr/bin/env bash)

**Exec Script**

```
service monitoring-daemon stop
cd /home/push/monitoring/target
rm -rf Monitoring.jar
ls -la | grep Monitoring | grep -v grep | awk '{print $9}' | xargs -I file mv file Monitoring.jar
service monitoring-daemon start
```

**Console Output**

```
    10:26:25 SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [service monitoring-daemon stop
    10:26:25 cd /home/push/monitoring/target
    10:26:25 rm -rf Monitoring.jar
    10:26:25 ls -la | grep Monitoring | grep -v grep | awk '{print $9}' | xargs -I file mv file Monitoring.jar
    10:26:25 service monitoring-daemon start] ...
    10:26:25 SSH: EXEC: connected
    10:26:25 bash: service: command not found
    10:26:25 bash: line 4: service: command not found
    10:26:25 SSH: EXEC: completed after 201 ms
    10:26:25 SSH: Disconnecting configuration [*********] ...
    10:26:25 ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [127]]
    10:26:25 Build step 'Send files or execute commands over SSH' changed build result to UNSTABLE
    10:26:25 [ANALYSIS-COLLECTOR] Computing warning deltas based on reference build #48
```

My Jenkins is using bash as default shell, and remote server also bash.

**Remote Server .bashrc**

```
# .bashrc
alias service='/sbin/service'
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions
```

**Remote Server .bash_profile**

```
# .bash_profile
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
```

is there any piece of configuration or step that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the full path for "service", ie..  replace "service" with "/usr/sbin/service"

Adding a first line like below might also help set  your path

`. /etc/profile`